# Pandas DataFrame - Add a character after every 2 position in a series

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following dataframe

| ID | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abcdefg |
| 2 | xkie |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | yvv12 |

I need to add a comma after every 2 characters in the Comment column, so the output would be

| ID | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ab.cd.ef.g |
| 2 | xk.ie |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | yv.v1.2 |

The code I tried but didn't work is:

`df['comment'] = '.'.join(df['comment'][i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(df['comment']), 2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.replace`. Insert dot `.` every 2 characters `\w{2}` except if this is the end of line `(?!$)`:

```
df['comment'] = df['comment'].str.replace(r'(\w{2}(?!$))', r'\1.', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ID     comment
0   1  ab.cd.ef.g
1   2       xk.ie
2   3         NaN
3   4     yv.v1.2
```

Comment: If a string has - in it, \w does not consider - as a character e.g. "as-sdr" will get converted to "as.-sd.r" any solution regarding this?

Comment: You can replace `\w` by `.` for any character: `r'(.{2}(?!$))'`